# How can I overflow undisplayed items in a listbox into another control

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to have a static (ie non scrolled) list of items displayed in a header, then, at the point an item can no longer fully render to the control I would like to push it to a more condensed view (heatmap or other yet to be decided visualisation).
The header control I had in mind was a simple list box with no scrolling. But ideally the solution would work against any items control.

I had thought to try and get some kind of pre-render (post layout) size to the control; do my own simple calc on the items it can display then crop the bound collection to that size taking remaining elements to another collection... but that seems fragile and clunky (and not quite sure how to get the size without a really unpleasant hack of grabbing it post render, performing my processing and then forcing an update... obviously even more unpleasant).

All offers of guidance appreciated...

Comment: You may try to write a [custom panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx#Panels_custom_panel_elements) that implements this special layout and use that panel as the ItemsPanel of an ItemsControl.